# Отображение UI при удалении программы (из установки/удаления)

Tags: wix

Есть задача: показать свой UI при удалении программы (из установки/удаления). Как я понимаю, там происходит force uninstall и никакого UI не отображается. Вопрос: можно ли решить данную задачу, не используя ARPNOREMOVE / ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT?
**upd:** В итоге мы пришли к выводу, что настолько наглый сетап, который по-тихому даже не позволяет удалить приложение - это плохой тон, и отказались от этой идеи. Тем не менее, насколько я смог найти, ответ userx - верный (скорее всего единственно-верный).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя Windows и не отображает пользовательских диалогов при удалении приложения из установки-удаления, задача показа собственного диалога вполне решается с помощью Custom Action, который запускает нужный диалог во время удаления приложения.

Comment: Нужно именно WizardPage показать, к сожалению...